# how to access request headers section in network tab from browser

Tags: angular

when the response is getting from API, Access date from request headers section from the network tab from browser. please help me out from this issue

Comment: Do you want to access request headers from Angular or your browser? And which browser?

Comment: I want to access request headers in angular from IE and chrome browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can 'tap' into your HttpResponse object in angular after the api call returns success. Use the tap operator by importing it this way:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And then in your Api service method, where you make your api call, pipe it to get the HttpResponse object:

```
demoServiceMethod(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`/api/<yoururl>`)
            .pipe(tap(event => {
                if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
                    console.log(event.headers);
                }
            }));
    }
```

Comment: It was not working properly, can u explain how to use or  can u post any other alternative method

Comment: Did you encounter any error? Can you post your code as well?